# Quotient of quotients in finite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, modules, quotient-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Suppose we are given filtrations of finite dimensional vectors spaces:
$$ B_d\subseteq Z_d\subseteq C_d$$
$$0 \subseteq C_{d,1} \subseteq C_d$$
$$0 \subseteq Z_{d,1} \subseteq Z_d$$ 
$$0 \subseteq B_{d,1} \subseteq B_d$$
Where $Z_{d,1}=Z_d\cap C_{d,1}$ and $B_{d,1}=B_d\cap C_{d,1}$.
Is it true that $$\frac{\frac{Z_d}{Z_{d,1}}}{\frac{B_d}{B_{d,1}}}\cong\frac{\frac{Z_d}{B_d}}{\frac{Z_{d,1}}{B_{d,1}}}?
$$

Comment: A factor $V/W$ only makes sense when $W\subseteq V$. Look at your first factor: $(\frac{Z_d}{Z_{d_1}})/(\frac{B_d}{B_{d_1}})$. It does not make sense a priori: $\frac{B_d}{B_{d_1}}$ is not a subset (or not even canonically identified as a subset) of $\frac{Z_d}{Z_{d_1}}$. For example, if $B_{d,1}=0$, $B_d\neq 0$ and $Z_{d,1}=Z_d$.

Comment: You are right, I edited the question. How about now?